# Realm Adding Object with Compound primaryKey Error

Tags: swift, primary-key, realm

I have a simple class

```
class FarmRecord: Object {
    dynamic var year = ""
    dynamic var month = ""
    dynamic var day = ""

    func setYearID(inYear: String) {
        self.year = inYear
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }
    func setMonthID(inMonth: String) {
        self.month = inMonth
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }
    func setDayID(inDay: String) {
        self.day = inDay
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }


    dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()

    private func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(year)\(month)\(day)"
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }
}
```

I tried to add object as follow:

```
let storeRealm = try! Realm()
let farm = FarmRecord()
farm.setYearID("2016")
farm.setMonthID("3")
farm.setDayID("1")
do {
    try storeRealm.write {
        storeRealm.add(farm)
    }
} catch {
}
```

And I see a crash with `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1)`. I even tried `storeRealm.add(farm, update: true)` with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm appears to be mishandling your `compoundKey` property due to it being marked as `lazy`. I've written up a [bug report about the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3337). As a workaround I'd suggest removing the `lazy` modifier and initializing `compoundKey` to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for a fast answer. Do as you said and it works. I can add objects now.

Comment: I've just run into this very issue. I don't actually need to property to be stored and have added it to the ignoreProperties. I still get the same crash.

Comment: @DanielWood, please file an issue in the [Realm GitHub repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) so we can help understand what you're seeing and provide you with a workaround.